# Count agents crossing a Path

Tags: count, anylogic

I'm looking for a method to count the agents crossing a particular path during a specific time. I know when you use pedestrians you can use the ped flow statistics, but is there also something for specific agents?

Thanks,
Aron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Rectangular Area" shapes have a code box "on enter" when you enable their "Access restriction" property. Just make sure to set the capacity to `infinity` (so access is never actually restricted).

Now, you can use those to count entering agents whenever you need:
[image]

Comment: Thanks benjamin! So than in the code box you just use a function to set a counter ++1 everytime something enters.

Comment: Exactly. In your case, you may only want to count during specifc times, but that is a different issue